# Acessing and transferring files from a FTP server to my ftp server through cron file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, cron, ftp

I have a FTP Server that uses Cron to automate tasks and I would like to use it to access another ftp server, get a file that starts with 26 and have an extension .csv, transfer to my FTP I am running the cron and delete the file on the origin FTP server, every friday of the week. Can somebody help me with the script code?

What I have right now is this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

filename="dir/*.csv"
hostname="files.test"
username="testuser"
password="testpassword"

ftp -in $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password

binary
get $filename
quit
EOF
```

Please, help

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please post the issue that you faced with your code.

Comment: I was able to solve it using the code answered and changing the local directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=user
PASS=password
URL=myIP
PLACE=tmp
#
ftp -v -n > /tmp/xftpb.log <<EOF
        open $URL
        user $USER $PASS
        binary
        cd $PLACE
        mget 26*.csv
        mdel 26*.csv
        quit
EOF
```

To run every friday, 8:00h, use at crontab:

```
0 8 * * 5     /path/mybash.sh
```

Comment: What is the /tmp/xftpb.log for?

Comment: It showed me this error:
line 7: /logs/xftpb.log: No such file or directory

Comment: I deleted this command, now the message shows this:

Connected to *my_ftp*.
220 FTP
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
250 Directory successfully changed.
221 Goodbye.

Seems like the mget command is not working